# Avoid store logs in AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a serverless architecture with a few AWS lambdas up and running sending logs to Cloudwatch right now.

**Question:** Is there any option to avoid send logs to Cloudwatch and redirect them to another tool?

**Example:** Catch all logs from stdout, avoid send it to Cloudwatch (of course, I don't need to pay for Cloudwatch storage) and send all these logs to another external tool such as New Relic, Splunk, etc?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Lambda only directly supports writing to CW logs. CW logs support streaming to other services such as S3 and Elasticsearch. You can implement your own logging code inside of your lambda to write output to external services, but that won't cover the log messages regarding the function invocation

Comment: So the only way to skip Cloudwatch is not showing my logging in standard output and sending the data to the other logging tool?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the tricky via removing Cloudwatch logs permissions from the role of your lambda.